# iOS App Opening App Store to Specific Product for Download Won't Accept Password SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an app that opens up the app store to a specific product for free download.  No matter what we try we keep getting ...

"The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect.  Please try again."

We have tried with multiple phones, multiple accounts and getting the same thing.  If we go to the app store directly the download works fine.

The only difference that we see is that we have the "GET" and "INSTALL" buttons instead of the "CLOUD ->" on the app store that works.

Any hints on this?

```
    SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    [storeProductViewController setDelegate: self];
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier && productID)
        parameters[SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier] = productID;
    if (systemVersion >= 8.0 && SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken && affiliateCode)
        parameters[SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken] = affiliateCode;
    if (systemVersion >= 8.0 && SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken && campainToken)
        parameters[SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken] = campainToken;

    [storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters: parameters completionBlock:
     ^(BOOL result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"App Download"
                                                             message: error.userInfo[@"NSLocalizedDescription"]
                                                            delegate: nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                                   otherButtonTitles: nil];
              [alert show];
         }
         else
             if (viewController.navigationController)
                 [viewController.navigationController  presentViewController: storeProductViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
             else
                 [viewController presentViewController: storeProductViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up on this is that all is working in the App Store Version of the app.  Not sure what is happening in development.